# Don't know how to make template

Tags: c++, templates

its short homework to make template of functions that cath exceptions. When i use char* its works.

When I try change char on T - it's dont working, help me with language.

```
template<class T>
class MemBuffer
{
public:

    MemBuffer(T inSize)
        :
        mpBuff(new char[inSize])
    {
    }

    ~MemBuffer()
    {
        delete[] mpBuff;
    }

    char* get() const { return mpBuff; }

protected:

    char* mpBuff;
};


//Its must work with this 

double f2()
{
    MemBuffer <int> buff( 20000);

    memset(buff.get(), 0, 20000);

    f1();                      // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

     return 6.6;
}
```

Comment: What does the `f1` function look like? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Off Topic 1: The argument of the constructor (`inSize`) is the allocated size, so (if I understand correctly what do you want) `inSize` should be `std::size_t` or another integer type, not `T`.

Comment: Off Topic 2: the size of `memset()` (third argument) is a number of bytes; the allocated size inside `MemBuffer` is counted in `sizeof(T)`, so `memset(buff.get, 0, 20000)` is correct only if `sizeof(T) == 1`; example of correct version: `memset(buff.get(), 0, sizeof(int)*20000);`

Comment: it isnt obvious what you want `Membuffer` to be parametrized on. Currently the only place you use `T` is for the size passed to the constructor, but `Membuffer<T>` always holds a `char* mpBuff;` no matter what `T` is. Please explain what the code should do and how it fails to do that. "not working" is not sufficient to explain the issue

Comment: in other words, your `MemBuffer` is not necessarily wrong. Probably it is not what you want, but what do you want?

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to have any relation to the assignment of "*make template of functions that catch exceptions*". Please clarify.

Comment: int f1()
{
    throw 5.6;

    cout << "THIS STRING WILL NEVER BE SHOWN";

    return 55;
} its f1 function

Answer (score 0):

ok i found, some comments was helpful, thank to all.

```
template<class T>
```

class MemBuffer

{

public:

```
MemBuffer(T inSize)
    :
   mpBuff( new T[inSize])
{
}

~MemBuffer()
{
    delete[] mpBuff;
}


T* get() const { return mpBuff; }
```

protected:

```
T* mpBuff;
```

};

and

```
double f2()
```

{

MemBuffer  buff( 20000);

```
memset( (void*)buff.get(), 0, 20000);

f1();                      


return 6.6;
```

}

Comment: if that is what you want then constructor should be `MemBuffer(size_t inSize)`. The size type is the same no matter what is the type of the arrays elements